# Item Selection from combo-box using vba in Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

The below values represent a combobox / combo-list on a website. I am trying to select item #3 from the drop down using VBA. I have tried several things, but I have had no luck selecting said item. I have tried looking for solutions on Google and the Stack but haven't found anything that seems to work.

```
<DIV id=ext-gen256 class="x-layer x-combo-list x-combo-list-small" style="FONT-SIZE: 10px; HEIGHT: 92px; WIDTH: 113px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 744px; Z-INDEX: 12007; TOP: 235px; VISIBILITY: visible">

<DIV id=ext-gen257 class=x-combo-list-inner style="HEIGHT: 90px; WIDTH: 111px">

<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="0">Select</DIV>
<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="1">Item 1</DIV>
<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="2">Item 2</DIV>
<DIV class=""x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="3">Item 3</DIV>
<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="4">Item 4</DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

I have used several variatons of the below code to try and select the item in question (i.e item #3), but keep getting a runtime error

```
Dim inputE As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
Set inputE = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("x-combo-list-item")
If inputE.innerText = "Item 3" Then
    inputE.Select
End If
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd have to add the "x-combo-selected" into your class name since that's how it shows in the HTML